# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: No address associated with <port>

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I'm writing a wsdl file and when I tested it, I got the "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: No address associated with " message. I've added address to the port tag:
Following is the code:

```
<service name="MyWebService">
    <documentation>WSDL file for Web Service</documentation>
    <port name="GetNamePortType" binding="tns:GetNameBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/site/ws/wsdl/"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language do you use in background? Last time I used SOAP was in classic asp a while ago :).
But there I had to specify the target file like this:

```
  <service name='TQ' >
    <port name='TQSoapPort' binding='wsdlns:TQSoapBinding' >
      <soap:address location='http://vminformer/latest/_Service/_service.asp' />
    </port>
  </service>
```

Don't know if that helps you, but without more information it is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'm using PHP. I've added "index.php" at the end of the location but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Check this: this is a tutorial, maybe this helps: http://devzone.zend.com/25/php-soap-extension/

Comment: Thanks YvesR, I followed the tutorial and rewrite the WSDL file and it works now!